# if f(x) if differentiable and continuous, prove $\frac{af(a)-bf(b)}{a-b} = f(c) + cf'(c) $

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable at $(a,b)$ and continuous at $[a,b]$ prove that there exist $ c \in (a,b)$ such that:
$$
\frac{af(a)-bf(b)}{a-b} = f(c) + cf'(c)
$$

I started with: let $c \in (a,b) $

$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$

But I have no clue how to continue from here, how can I transform it to this form? :S

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apply your mean value theorem to some function other than $f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** apply the Lagrange theorem to the function $g(x)=x\cdot f(x)$.

Comment: is there no difference between a hint and an answer? a proper place for a hint is the comment section to the question.

Comment: @abel: this site is designed for providing answers, not comments.

Comment: hint $\neq$ answer

Comment: @abel: the OP was explicitly asking for *suggestions*. What's wrong with replying?

Comment: if it were a hint, you could leave it in the comment section like user @GEdgar did. that gives the op time to work something out first. at least you could wait for sometime before you put your answer up.

Comment: @abel: Many problem posers ask for hints more than complete answers. In such a case, we usually reply with answers ($\neq$ comments) containing hints. The comments space is not designed for answering questions, by the site policies.